# C# Treeview, how to keep only one rootline checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Using WinForms, desktop app.

When node is checked, I have to uncheck nodes that does not share same root. So if I have 5 roots, with multiple childs ( deep tree ) and I check node that is child of root 1, I need to uncheck root 2-5 and all childs.

Do I really have to go through all nodes to uncheck them? This becomes quite heavy, if I have 10 roots with 30+ child each?

EDIT:
So, my use case is, that I need to be able to have possibility to select all nodes, but only one rootnode. With root, I mean the very first node and siblings of that. So if I check node that is located in other base root node, then all other roots and child's are unchecked. Only one root can be active at time.

1. root

   1. child1
   2. child2
2. root2

   1. child3
   2. child4

So checking child4, unchecks root, child1 and child2

Comment: winforms, I had the tag, but did not mentions it in the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never "heavy" when you use recursion, the natural way to visit the nodes of a tree.  You simply iterate the siblings of the checked node and recurse to visit their children and uncheck them as well.  Like this:

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Node.Checked) {
        for (var node = e.Node.PrevNode; node != null; node = node.PrevNode) uncheckTree(node);
        for (var node = e.Node.NextNode; node != null; node = node.NextNode) uncheckTree(node);
    }
}

private void uncheckTree(TreeNode node) {
    node.Checked = false;
    foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes) uncheckTree(child);
}
```

Comment: Halfway there. It does not affect root level at all. But affects all the levels after that. I edit question, to be more clear. Thanks for this already.